# What is the name of this man who made three pianos play at once?

Tags: piano

I remember hearing a segment (almost certainly on NPR) about a man who played a piano while two other pre-programmed pianos used an algorithm to change what he was playing into another pattern and play along at the same time. Does anyone know who this artist is?

Comment: Welcome! Please check out [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This might be a bit too much of a "trivia" question to be on-topic. But you might edit it to ask more about *how* this was accomplished, which would be much more relevant. Please explain a bit more, too; I'm wondering why "pianos" were used when a computer running Reaktor or the like would be a lot easier. Unless it means this was done in an entirely analog and mechanical way, which would be FASCINATING.

Comment: @AndyBonner I'm not sure how this is a trivia question and not just an identification question, since I don't know the answer and I'm asking if someone in the community can find the answer for me. I really don't remember much, but all I seem to recall is that there were three pianos, and two of them were playing by themselves.

Comment: My read is that it's an identification question, which are off topic.

Comment: Please see conversations around https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=identification. This SE doesn't cover simple "what is this" questions, and "who is this" is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Ólafur Arnalds?  I've seen him live, he has pianos rigged with some kind of responsive system - they seem to be reacting to the audience murmurs  before he'd even come on stage.

Edit: he calls them "Ghost Pianos", and has definitely done a Tiny Desk

Comment: And there's an actual NPR article, probably what the OP is remembering: https://www.npr.org/2018/07/19/630111211/one-key-many-notes-lafur-arnalds-piano-rig-fuses-technology-and-musicality

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it. Thank you for your answer!